# Matplotlib how to tell if an artist is a line or a legend line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# number of points
N = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N)
y = np.cos(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, label='cos(x)')
legend = plt.legend()
legend_line, = legend.get_lines()
```

I want to create function `print_info` that takes an argument `artist` and tells if it's an actual line that is drawn on the axis OR a legend line.

Therefore:

```
def print_info(artist):
   # Assuming that artist could be either an actual line or a legend line
   # if artist is an actual line
   print("Artist is an actual line)
   # else
   print("Artist is a legend line")
```

One way I can think of is to compare the size of `x_data`. That is if `artist.get_xdata().size == N` then it's an actual line, otherwise it's a legend line.

Is there a **proper way** to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

So far I have found another way to tell the difference between the two artists by checking if they are members of `ax.get_children()`:

```py
def print_info(artist):
  if artist in ax.get_children():
     print("The artist is an actual line.")
  else:
     print("The artist is a legend line.")
```